# Calling an empty function from Android layout file crashes App

Tags: android, function, layout

I have a checkbox in the Android layout file. When the checkbox is clicked i call an empty function in the activity class. This causes the app to stop working. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using the "onclick" attribute in your XML.

If you are receiving a MethodNotFound exception, it could be one of two things:

You have a typo in either your Activity's method name or your XML's method name, or...

The visibility of your method in your Activity is not public.

When specifying onclick values in XML, the method should look like this in your activity:

```
public void myOnClickMethod(View v) { ... }
```

Comment: I think that's it, i didn't have the view parameter. Thank you.